# Vue momentjs update relative time in real time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, momentjs

How I can do update relative time from `momentjs` in real time for user?

I have computed:

```
computed: {
  ago() {
     return moment().fromNow();
    },
}
```

And when I use in component this:

```
<span class="text-muted pr-2" v-text="ago"></span>
```

I get static text: `a few seconds ago`, how update this text without page reloading? I want see: `a minute ago`, a `two minutes ago` e.t.c..

How I can do this in real time for user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `moment().fromNow()` isn't reactive so you will  not see any change,to deal with we fix an old time property which should be initialized in the `created` hook *`this.oldTime = new Date();`*, and set a time interval with **1s**, based on the old time property we call *`moment(this.old).fromNow();`* to update our property *`ago`*.

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      ago: '',
      oldTime: '',
    interval:null
    }
  },
 destroyed(){
   clearInterval(this.interval)
   },
  created() {
    this.oldTime = new Date();
    this.interval=setInterval(() => {
      this.ago = moment(this.oldTime).fromNow();
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">

  <span class="text-muted pr-2" >
  {{ago}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Based on the comment of @Badgy :

> ***`How would you handle it for a v-for where you show it in the UI via a function? I thought about attaching it to the message object on created and update all message objects every x seconds but not sure if its the best way`***

to fit to this situation we should create a time interval in which we update the `ago` property of each message :

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {

      messages: [{
          content: 'Hello !',
          time: '2019-09-10 00:08'
        },
        {
          content: 'Hello again!',
          time: '2019-09-10 00:10'
        }
      ],
  interval:null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    msgs() {
      return messages

    }
  },
       destroyed(){
   clearInterval(this.interval)
   },
  created() {

    this.interval=setInterval(() => {

      this.messages = this.messages.map(m => {
        m.ago = moment(m.time).fromNow();
        return m;
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

```css
.primary{
color:blue
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container">

  <ul>
    <li v-for="m in messages">{{m.content}} <span class="primary">{{m.ago}}</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How would you handle it for a `v-for` where you show it in the UI via a function? I thouht about attaching it to the message object on created and update all message objects every x seconds but not sure if its the best way

Comment: i can't understand your use case, could you post a full question in which you explain it clearly

Comment: No need for seperate post, its very simple: Imagine you fetch a Chat from a Server where you use Momentjs to display the timestamp of it, now for rendering a list of messages your approach does not fit so I wanted to ask if you have any idea for it

Comment: You mean a list of messages with send time, and you want you show the relative time for each message ?

Comment: Yes, currently I have that but they do not refresh and I feel like setting an interval for each msg is dumb so I thought maybe I set an interval and define it as a Property of the msg rather than calling a method from the template like I do right now

Comment: Thanks, I think if you would pass the object message onto a child component you need to use Vue.set instead of assigning it due to reactivty problems comming with it (had to do it in my case) just if someone stumbles upon it

Comment: Isn't it also necessary to delete the interval in the `destroyed()` hook?

Comment: not a must but is a recommended practice to remove started in a component interval in the `destroyed()` hook

Answer (score 8):

I solve this using a global "ticker" in my Vuex store. It starts incrementing itself on load every 30 seconds. Descriptive messages of the time compare to this ticker instead of to other implementations of "now" or whatever. The advantage of this technique over something like every UI element iterating its own datetime ticker every second is that you don't have reactive elements in Vue all refreshing themselves on a regular basis all willy nilly. In my application, the one global "pseudo-now" ticker iterates every 30 seconds and all elements which provide descriptive accounts of the time all refresh at once in one frame. This benefits performance.

snippet from a relevant Vuex store:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

const TICKER_INTERVAL = 30000; // milliseconds

let tickerPointer = null;

const data = {
  state: {
    now: new Date,
  },

  mutations: {
    refreshTicker(state) {
      state.now = new Date;
    },
  },

  actions: {
    startTicker({commit}) {
      if (tickerPointer === null) {
        tickerPointer = setInterval(() => {
          commit('refreshTicker');
        }, TICKER_INTERVAL);
      }
    },

    haltTicker({state}) {
      clearInterval(tickerPointer);
      state.now = null;
      tickerPointer = null;
    },
```

"StartTicker" is dispatched once by the top of my application upon load.

Comment: Love this solution :).