# Vue momentjs update relative time in real time from timestamp

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, momentjs, vuex

I'm building a forum app and with v-for, I want to show when all the comments were posted with momentjs relative time, the problem is that the render never changes from 'A few seconds ago'.
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280249/vue-momentjs-update-relative-time-in-real-time), the response show to achieve what I want, basically using an interval when the component is created:

```
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.messages = this.messages.map(m => {
        m.ago = moment(m.time).fromNow();
        return m;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

But due to that I fetch the data directly from vuex, I don't get how to integrate the solution with my code.

This is my store.js:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    comments: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    loadComments: (state, comments) => {
      state.comments = comments;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    loadComments: async (context) => {
      let snapshot = await db
        .collection("comments")
        .orderBy("timestamp")
        .get();
      const comments = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let appData = doc.data();
        appData.id = doc.id;
        appData.timestamp = moment()
          .startOf(doc.data().timestamp)
          .fromNow();
        comments.push(appData);
      });
      context.commit("loadComments", comments);
    },
  },
});
```

And this my script:

```
import { db, fb } from "../firebase";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Forum",
  data() {
    return {
      commentText: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getComment();
  },
  methods: {
    getComment() {
      this.$store.dispatch("loadComments");
    },
    async sendComment() {
      await db
        .collection("comments")
        .add({
          content: this.commentText,
          author: this.name,
          timestamp: Date.now()
        });
      this.commentText = null;
      this.getComment();
    }
  },
  created() {
    let user = fb.auth().currentUser;
    this.name = user.displayName;
  },
  computed: mapState(["comments"])
};
```

Comment: could you provide a running code as i have in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54282054/8172857)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, I could do it... But won't work anyway because I bring the data from firebase.
however, I could fill the the comments array in the state with hardcoded data but I think that the question point would be missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to abstract all of this logic into a single component for displaying dates, rather then needing to trigger updates across code boundaries. Keep all your date rendering code as minimal as possible so that it is easy to change your date rendering logic at any time.

The date itself is data, but the visual representation of that date is not. So I wouldn't store the formatted date in the Vuex store.

Create a component `<from-now>` which takes a `date` as a prop and renders the date using moment's `fromNow`. It also takes care of updating itself periodically (every minute). Since it is a component, you can display the full date as a tooltip so that users can know the exact time when they mouse over it.

```js
const components = new Set();

// Force update every component at the same time periodically
setInterval(() => {
  for (const comp of components) {
    comp.$forceUpdate();
  }
}, 60 * 1000);

Vue.component('FromNow', {
  template: '<span :title="title">{{ text }}</span>',
  props: ['date'],
  
  created() {
    components.add(this);
  },
  
  destroyed() {
    components.remove(this);
  },
  
  computed: {
    text() {
      return moment(this.date).fromNow();
    },
    
    title() {
      return moment(this.date).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    // Test various seconds ago from now
    dates: [5, 60, 60 * 5, 60 * 60].map(sec => moment().subtract(sec, 'seconds')),
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-for="date of dates">
    <from-now :date="date"></from-now>
  </p>
</div>
```

For the sake of simplicity, `<from-now>` only displays relative dates. I use a similar component to this, but more general-purpose. It takes a `format` prop which allows me to choose how I want the date to be displayed (it can be a relative time, or a specific date format that moment accepts).

Comment: It's a very nice solution, but the problem still the same... I don't know how integrate with my current code, how can I pass the timestamp that I get from firebase as prop to that component?

Comment: I don't understand why it isn't working. In your code, you are doing `moment(m.time)` which implies that `m.time` is a JavaScript compatible date string or timestamp. My component does the exact same thing. Just pass the raw, unformatted date you get from firebase to the `date` prop on the component.

Comment: Now it's working, i was passing the formatted date instead of the raw data, thank you very much.

Comment: The tooltip was a great extra XD, thanks for that again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another action and dispatch it every second :

```
 mutations: {
    loadComments: (state, comments) => {
      state.comments = comments;
    },
   update:(state)=>{
    state.comments=state.comments.map(comment=>{
     comment.ago= moment()
          .startOf(comment.timestamp)
          .fromNow();
        return comment;
     });
   }
  },
 actions: {
  updateComments(context){
   context.commit('update')
   },  
  loadComments: async (context) => {
    ....
```

and

```
 created() {
    let user = fb.auth().currentUser;
    this.name = user.displayName;
 setInterval(() => {
      this.$store.dispatch("updateComments");
    }, 1000);
  },
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: comments is not defined`, here is an image of the [error](https://i.ibb.co/J7VRGst/2.png)

Comment: sorry i missed `state` before `comments` it should be `state.comments=state.comments.map(comment=>{`

Comment: There's no error in the console anymore, but it still doesn't work... The vuex tab in the vue developers tools shows the payload of the `update` mutation as undefined.