# Use moment().fromNow() with a vue component in array

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

How can I use Momentjs to format a date that is inside my vue component? The moment().fromNow() function works fine when I manually put in a date, but I want to use the date that is fetched from my API.

This is currently what it looks like, I put the part where I need help with in *.

Vue.js

```
 <div class="post d-flex flex-row" v-for="(post, i) in Post" :key="i">
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Posted **{{moment(datePosted).fromNow()}}** by {{post.user}}</h6>
 </div>

data() {
        return{
            Post: []
        }
    },
    async created() {
        try{
            const res = await axios.get(url)
            this.Post = res.data;
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue momentjs update relative time in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280249/vue-momentjs-update-relative-time-in-real-time)

Comment: No, I am trying to basically do something like {{moment({{post.datePosted}}).fromNow()}}. But I cannot put a component into the moment function like that

Comment: but this will not be reactive

Answer (score 1):

Variable `datePosted` seems undefined. The format function should be something like `{{ moment(post.datePosted).fromNow() }}`. Also don't use variables which differ just by the case: `post` and `Post`.

Comment: oh wow it was that simple. I think I need to take a break, I am starting to over think things now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you could map `res.data` inside created and append attribute with formatted data to the object.
E.g:

```
this.Post = res.data.map(post => ({
   ...post,
   datePost: moment(post.date).fromNow()
})
```

Obviously, I cannot know if post.date is proper attribute. You have to type there the proper one. Also make sure you imported moment js module.

Then in the template, you could use:

```
{{ post.datePost }}
```